# Swift Base64 Format

Tags: swift, base64

On this website, for example when you drop in an image, it is turned into a proper base64 format: http://base64image.org/

In my Swift app, here is what I have to generate a base64 string from an image:

```
let image_Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(default_image)
let base64String = image_Data!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
```

This gives me something similar, but it has spaces and line breaks. How do I get an output just like the output from the website above?

Comment: Include some sample output from the code and the website for the same image so we can see the difference and understand your problem

Answer (score 1):

```
let image_Data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(default_image)
let base64String = image_Data!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([]) // Don't ask for line breaks
```

If you remove the request for line breaks, does it match what you're expecting?

Comment: Thank you! This gives me the error: "Missing argument for parameter #1 in call"

Comment: .base64EncodedStringWithOptions([]) or .base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions())

Comment: Fixed based on @LeoDabus's comment.

Comment: @Kaptain I don't understand the question. This is Swift.