# Convert UIImage to base64 string in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage, base64, uiimagepngrepresentation

I'm trying to convert a UIImage to a base64 string with the goal of uploading it to a back-end server.

However, the conversion code I found in this article (which should be Apple's own implementation) generates an invalid string:

[Convert between UIImage and Base64 string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11251340/convert-between-uiimage-and-base64-string)

After upload, I get this image:

[Failty image that is decoded from iOS converted base64 [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QHFOn.jpg)

Instead of this:

[Correct image decoded from an online base64 conversion tool[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcJQS.jpg)

I tested the upload results using Postman and the back-end handles a valid base64 image correctly, so I narrowed the bug down to the base64 conversion itself. Here's my code:

```
public extension UIImage
{
     func base64Encode() -> String?
    {
        guard let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(self) else
        {
            return nil
        }

        let base64String = imageData.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions.Encoding64CharacterLineLength)
        let fullBase64String = "data:image/png;base64,\(base64String))"

        return fullBase64String
    }
}
```

Any idea how I could fix my base64 output on my iOS device before I upload it to the server?

Comment: That looks absolutely correct to me, what makes you think it's the conversion? Have you checked the conversion algorithm server side?

Comment: Try `base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])`. You might also have to replace "+", "/" and "=", compare http://stackoverflow.com/a/39376534/1187415.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do it something like this:

**For Encoding:**

```
data.base64EncodedStringWithOptions([])
```

**For decoding:**

```
let url = URL(string: String(format:"data:application/octet-stream;base64,%@",base64String))
do {
    let data =  try Data(contentsOf: url!)
}catch {

}
```

Comment: If you use the `Data base64EncodedString(options:)` method to encode the `Data` to a `String`, then use the `Data init?(base64Encoded:, options:)` initializer to convert the string back into `Data`.

Answer (score 2):

for Swift 4, 
Do something like this,

**For Encoding -**

```
let imgObj = UIImage(named: "photo")    
let imageData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(imgObj!)! as NSData
let base64 = imageData.base64EncodedData(options: .lineLength64Characters)
```

datatype of base64 variable is Data.